# How do you enable panning instead of grabbing with Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape.js

For situations where a parent node covers most of the screen, how can left-clicking and moving the mouse enable panning and not grabbing?

When I set grabbing to false for the parent node, and I left-click on the parent node and move the mouse, nothing happens.

Edit: I would like to apply the equivalent of [panify()](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.panify) but ideally I can do it when declaring the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to set *pannable* to true when defining the node.